# For splitting the data, does pytorch do it by itself randomly if I don’t specify split ratio?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

For splitting the data, does pytorch do it by itself randomly if I don’t specify split ratio?

I am working on pytorch deep learning model autoencoder, i have dataset (csv file) with 10 classes and 500 000 rows.
I removed the label column.

I saw one research paper code and they did not split code instead they removed label from dataset (csv file)

Comment: You always have to do it, no framework does it "automatically".

Comment: PyTorch doesn't automatically split datasets. You need to explicitly define the split ratio.

Comment: You can either define a ratio and split the dataset with a fixed seed or provide a file of instance names. The latter facilitates reproducibility and transparency.